# django-autocomplete-light add parameter to query url

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to pass some data along to the `autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase` so I can exclude some models from the search. I'm trying to use the Dependencies info in the docs [here](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependant.html)

but I can seem to get it.

The id of the input is `id_alternate_version-autocomplete`, so I'm trying:

```
$("#id_alternate_version-autocomplete").yourlabsWidget().autocomplete.data = {'id': 'foo'};
```

But the url called looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/autocomplete/FooAutocomplete/?q=bar`

I want: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/autocomplete/FooAutocomplete/?q=bar&id=foo`

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#recipe').on('change propertychange keyup input paste', function() {
        var ingredient_item_type    = $("form#recipe input[type='radio']:checked").val();
        var widget                  = $("form#recipe input#id_ingredients_text").parents('.autocomplete-light-widget');
        if(ingredient_item_type) {
widget.yourlabsWidget().autocomplete.data['hello'] = 'world';
        }
    });
});
```

Javascript acrobatics aside, the key observation is thus:

*anything you put in the `.data` object of the autocomplete widget will
automatically be made part of the GET request*.  HTH.

Comment: Cool. I'm gonna go ahead and give you answer credit for your solution. Though I solved it (a couple months ago) by simply writing my own jQuery.autocomplete event for the field in question.

Comment: Thanks.  I found your answer while solving it myself, and answered as a way of paying it forward to other users of this library.  It is documented in a roundabout way here:  https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/docs_rewrite/cookbook.html#low-level-basics

Answer (score 4):

DAL provides a way to do this with "forwarding" of another rendered form field's value.

See http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form