# django-autocomplete-light add parameter to query url (in version 3.5.1)

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django-autocomplete-light in a django admin change_form.html page, however I need to change dynamically the GET parameters of the URL depending on another field.

I have already tried to replicate this answer [django-autocomplete-light add parameter to query url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409293/django-autocomplete-light-add-parameter-to-query-url), but failed since I am using version 3

Tried this way:

```
$("#id_city").change(function(){
    url = '{% url "custom-pop-autocomplete" %}';
    $('#id_p').attr('data-autocomplete-light-url', url + `?city=${$(this).val()}`);
    $('#id_p').trigger('autocompleteLightInitialize');
});
```

This way:

```
$('[data-autocomplete-light-function=select2]:not([id*="__prefix__"])').each(function() {
    $(this).initialize
});
```

and this way:

```
$('[data-autocomplete-light-function=select2]:not([id*="__prefix__"])').each(function() {
    window.__dal__initialize(this);
});
```

None of them working to reinitialize django-autocomplete-light. I just need to change the URL.